# I have an error in AndroidManifest.xml in creating SQLite Database

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DNu4.png)
This is the message shown when I pointed the cursor to the word

Comment: Quoting the message: "To fix this warning, decide whether your application should support backup, and explicitly set `android:allowBackup=(true|false)`". It means that you have to add that attribute on the `<application>` element, and set it to either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Note that this is a warning, not an error.